# ImageView в ScrollView лагает

Tags: java, android

При скроллинге подлагивает скроллвью. Как это можно исправить?
Размер картинки 1200x600

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/vkl3"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/imgone">




<ScrollView
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="13%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="36%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
   >


   <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >



     <ImageView
         app:layout_aspectRatio="48%"
         app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
         android:src="@drawable/imgforthird"/>

       </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>



    </ScrollView>


    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это происходит из-за размера картинки и из-за обработки её в основном, `UI` потоке. Решение - уменьшить картинку и/или отображать её асинхронно.

Последнее  можно сделать с помощью либ для отображения картинок - UIL или Picasso.

Comment: к сожалению Picasso не справиться, столкнувшись с такой проблемой, я сжимал картинку до более приемлемого качества.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСуетин, не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду, но у меня после отображения картинок UIL-ом лаги в ScrollView исчезли.

Comment: К сожалению когда была картинка хорошего качества, тогда лаги не пропадали, количество выделяемой оперативной памяти было порядка 200мб и это на экране видел 1 картинку

Comment: @ЕвгенийСуетин, а если UIL-ом?.. Вы же про Picasso?

Comment: Когда я начал использовать UIL то уже применял сжатие, так что проверить не довелось.

Answer (score 1):

Использовал стороннюю библиотеку nostra13 Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Подключение и использование не вызывает особых трудностей.
в builder.gradle

```
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

Объявить:

```
public DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;
```

Задать настройки и вывести:

```
    defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .build();
    
            config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                    .build();
    
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(image_url, product_logo);
```

Стоит ознакомиться на GitHub подробнее, опций много. Мне, пока, хватает минимальных.

Спасибо замечаниям в комментариях. Библиотека давно не поддерживается. В своем проекте внес правки в пользу Glide. Поскольку у меня в проекта используется ScrollView, а его элементы заполняются в отдельном классе, пример одного метода класса.

```
//image_url       - адрес картинки
//contextLocalVar - передаваемый контекст

    public void setProduct_logo(String image_name) {
       
       String  image_url = "http://www.smc-r.online/resource/" + image_name;
       Glide
            .with(contextLocalVar)
            .load(image_url)
            .into(product_logo);
    }
```

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит заменить библиотеку на Glide, т.к. UIL, судя по репозиторию, в последний раз обновлялась 5 лет назад и с тех пор не поддерживается.

Comment: Опробовал. Пожалуй, соглашусь полностью. Внес правки в проект. Спасибо.